# React useMemo with a onClick calling a method

Tags: reactjs

I'm having issues with React useMemo and a onClick calling a function. It says I need to add the function as the useMemo dependency, but when I add it the function makes the useMemo Hook change on every render.

```
const test = useMemo(() => {
   return myData.map((obj, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
           <button type="button" onClick={() => myFunc(index)}>Test</button>
        </div>
      )
   });
}, [myData]);
```

It returns the warning: `React Hook useMemo has a missing dependency: 'myFunc'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

I try to include it in the dependencies `[myData, myFunc]`. Then, it returns: `The 'myFunc' function makes the dependencies of useMemo Hook (at line 105) change on every render. Move it inside the useMemo callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'myFunc' in its own useCallback() Hook`

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: can you add the code of your myFunc function ?

Comment: @Shyam it is just a test application, I'm trying to understand how React works. myFunc can be just a console.log(parameter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are three cases; If your function desn't depend on any state inside your component (i.e. it has no side-effects), then you can make it a pure function and put it outside you component definition; but if it does, then there are two cases: either your function is called only inside that useMemo hook, in which case you can just put the function definition in there like this:

```
const test = useMemo(() => {
   const myFunc = () => {}
   return myData.map((obj, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
           <button type="button" onClick={() => myFunc(index)}>Test</button>
        </div>
      )
   });
}, [myData]);
```

but if you want to put it outside that useMemo & call it everywhere inside that component (or maybe pass it to a child component), just wrap it in a useCallback hook so it wouldn't be redeclared on every render & wouldn't change the dependany array. this way you wouldn't change anything in the useMemo hook & just wrap your myFunc function like this:

```
const MemoizedMyFunct = useCallback(
// put your function definition here
, [
// fill the dependency array with the variables used inside your function
])
```

Comment: How could I wrap in a useCallback? Could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 2):

I'd really advise against using this hook like you are doing now, per the react docs, useMemo hook is "best" as it helps avoid expensive calculations on every render.
The above to me is more of a list being rendered with each list item doing some stuff on click.

- May I suggest you make this a component instead like so:
  You'll see that I used `memo` so that the rendered components i.e the `MyListItemComponent` & `myListComponent` will both be memoized after render, that way if the something caused a rerender if the props are the same, react will skip the rendering of these 2 by using reusing the memoized result.

PS: Don't overuse React.memo though. Use it wisely as you may incur performance hits instead.

that said, assuming you are working with components that absolutely need to be memoized... see code suggestion below.

```
import React, { memo, useCallback } from 'react';


const MyListItemComponent = memo(( itemData, itemIndex ) => {

    const handleListItemClick = useCallback(() => {
        // ...code here that can even do stuff with itemIndex prop
    }, [itemIndex]);

    return (
      <div>
         <button type="button" onClick={handleListItemClick}>ListItem</button>
      </div>
    )
});



const myListComponent = memo(( myListData ) => {
   if (!myListData) {
      return;
   }

   return (
       <div id='container'>
           {
               myListData.map((myListItemData, mylistItemIndex) => {
                    return (
                        < MyListItemComponent key={index} itemIndex={mylistItemIndex} itemData={myListItemData} />
                    )
                })
           }
        </div>
    );
});
```